# Is it right to say that a positive measure is a signed measure by definition?

Tags: measure-theory

A signed measure $\mu$ is a measure which can also take on negative values. Now my question is, is a positive measure a special case of a signed measure since it essentially maps to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$? (Note: I am only considering finite measures)

Answer (score 0):

A signed measure is one which can, but need not, take both positive
and negative values.  The easiest characterization of a signed measure
to my knowledge is that there exists a positive measure with the same
measurable sets which dominates its magnitude such that countable additivity occurs for those unions for which the dominating measure is finite.